# Appropriate probability distribution for censored ratio data

Tags: distributions, censoring, ratio

I have two bacterial markers, I'll just call them *X* and *Y*. *X* codes for virulence, whereas *Y* just indicates the bacteria is present. Consequently, *X* will not show up without *Y* although not all bacteria have *X*. Both also have a detection limit, although I only care about the detection limit for *X* because I want to know the probability distribution for the ratio of *X* / *Y* (pathogenic to normal bacteria if present).

Because the data are censored and a ratio, I was considering fitting a censored beta distribution. However I realized that the ratio itself is not censored - for example, *X* could be below detection limit but still some large % of *Y* if *Y* is also fairly low.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to address this problem? I am assuming using a ratio distribution won't work because *X* and *Y* are obviously not independent.